# CSS break-word Not working in a Div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am iterating words from the db using ionic framework. The words spans across the div and never brakes on encountering the end of the div and instead the words truncates. I have applied break-word to my css but no good result achieved.

app.js file that returns the parent div:

```
$scope.isNotCurrentUserInner = function(user){

            if(current_user != user){
                return 'other_messages';
            }
            return 'messages';
        };
```

This is my css

```
.messages {
  background: #c2dfff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}
.messages div {
  font-size: 14.5px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
  color: #000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This is the display words

```
<li class="{{ isNotCurrentUserInner(msg.Name) }}">
    <div>{{ msg.Content }}</div>
</li>
```

This is the screen copy:
[image]
kindly assist!

Comment: can you show the real outcome (I mean screen copy)

Comment: is this <div>{{msg.Content}}</div> below your parent div with class .messages? In your css it shows that this div should be held by parent div with class="messages" if that's not the way it is , do it. If that container is held by parent div with a class , please provide us longer html code , thanks! )

Comment: Please provide full code that will allow us to reproduce your issue. The code you have currently provided (assuming the `div` is in a container with the class `.messages`) does not result in the same outcome. https://jsfiddle.net/z63wk3wz/

Comment: An edit has been made to include the parent div

Comment: @JnG can you show how the parent div sits around the `<div>{{msg.Content}}</div>` ?

Comment: @Aravona an edit has been made to show the parent div sitting around the <div>{{msg.Content}}</div>

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Your div does not have the class "messages" add that class and change ".messages div" to just ".messages".</strike>

If that doesn't help, try changing

"word-wrap: break-word;"
to
"word-break: break-all;"

Answer (score 1):

Reproducing what you've described in your question works *exactly* as you're expecting. You need to provide more information or a live example of your issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/jabark/pg0czu9L/

```css
.messages {
  background: #c2dfff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.messages div {
  font-size: 14.5px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
  color: #000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">
  <div>Helllooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
</div>
```